# Somar itens selecionados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `select` mostrando produtos que podem ser inseridos numa tabela clicando no botão  <kbd>+</kbd> .

> Anteriormente quando os valores eram apesentados no formato como está no banco de dados (`9999.99`) eu conseguia calcular o valor dos itens selecionados corretamente, mas quando passei a apresentar os valores no formato do Real (`9.999,99`) não consegui mais calcular o total dos produtos selecionados.

Estava aplicando uma conversão no cálculo dessa função:

```
function calculaTotal(){
  var total = 0;
  if ($(".iten-preco").length > 0){
    $(".iten-preco").each(function(){
      total += $(this).text();
    });
  }
  $('#total-orcamento').text(total);
}
```

Código completo:

```js
function loadItens(){
 $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/10hz22",function(data){
   itens = data;
   $.each(data, function(key, val){
     $("#select-iten").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+
     val.nome+" ("+ toReal(val.preco) +")</option>");
   });
 });
}

loadItens();

var itens;

$("#add-iten").click(function(){
  var si = $("#select-iten").val();
  $(".itens").append("<tr class='iten-added'>"+
    "<td>"+itens[si].id+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+itens[si].nome+"</td>"+
    "<td class='iten-preco'>"+ toReal(itens[si].preco) +"</td>"+
    "<td><button class='iten-delete btn btn-danger'>-</button></td>"+
  "</tr>");
  calculaTotal();
});

$(document).on("click", ".iten-delete", function(){
  $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  calculaTotal();
});

function calculaTotal(){
  var total = 0;
  if ($(".iten-preco").length > 0){
    $(".iten-preco").each(function(){
      total += $(this).text();
    });
  }
  $('#total-orcamento').text(total);
}

function toReal(str){
  str = parseFloat(str).toLocaleString('pt-br',{minimumFractionDigits: 2});
  return str;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline">
  <label for="select-iten">Produtos: </label>
  <select id="select-iten" class="form-control">
    <option>Selecione</option>
  </select>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="add-iten"  value="+"> 
</form>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Preço</th>
        <th>Ação</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="itens">
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Total: </td>
        <td colspan="2" id="total-orcamento"></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Se você alterar `total += $(this).text()`, para `total += $(this).text().replace('.','').replace(',','.')` não resolve o seu problema?

Comment: Teve que converter para `float` também!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem **dois erros** na função `calculaTotal`:

**01.** Levando em conta que você usa uma vírgula para separar as casas decimais, o JavaScript não entende que se trata de um número decimal. Desse modo, você deve fazer uma conversão para `float` **após** substituir a vírgula por um ponto.

Para realizar a conversão, você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
function toFloat(num) {
  return parseFloat(num.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '.'))
}

console.log(toFloat('987.654,321'))
```

**02.** Você está fazendo uma concatenação de strings ao usar o operador `+=` sem usar números em **ambos os operandos**. No entanto, esse problema já é resolvido pelo tópico anterior.

Um exemplo da concatenação não desejada que você está fazendo:

```js
let initialValue = 0

initialValue += '3'
initialValue += '5'

console.log(initialValue, typeof initialValue)
```

---

Então:

```
function calculaTotal() {
  var total = 0

  if ($('.iten-preco').length > 0) {
    $('.iten-preco').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '.'))
    })
  }
  $('#total-orcamento').text(total)
}
```

Comment: Com esse replace você só substitui a primeira ocorrência do caractere "."

Comment: É verdade! Obrigado pela observação. Nesse caso, expressões regulares como `/\./g` são mais convenientes... Vou editar a resposta! :)

Comment: Resolveu, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Converta para float:

```
    function calculaTotal() {
     var total = 0;
     if ($(".iten-preco").length > 0) {
       $(".iten-preco").each(function(){
         total += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/\./g, 
       '').replace(/,/g, '.'));
       });
     }
     $('#total-orcamento').text(total);
    }
```